# How to show a simple * after a component that is required?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, requiredfieldvalidator

I have this sample form:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <p:growl id="myGrowl" showDetail="true" life="5000" />
    <p:inputText value="#{pruebaBean.campoTexto}" required="true" requiredMessage="*" />
    <p:commandButton value="Ok" update="myForm" />
</h:form>
```

I want to show an * after the component that is required. The problem is that the requiredMessage shows it in the `p:growl` and it looks pretty bad.

I have to validate a lot of components in a very big form and adding a

```
<p:message for="componentName" display="icon" />
```

for each of them in the form will make it uglier.

It does not matters if no message is showed (I dont want them in the `p:message`), only turning those components required to red will be good too.

Hope You help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a 'label', do something like demonstrated in the [PrimeFaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/outputLabel.xhtml):

```
 <p:outputLabel for="extended" value="Extended Label:" />
 <p:inputText id="extended" required="true" />
```

or if you just want a 'star'

```
 <p:inputText id="extended" required="true" />
 <p:outputLabel for="extended" value="" />
```

And if you just want a marked border, look at the generated html of a required input

```
<input type="text" data-p-required="true" data-p-label="Extended Label" 
    class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all"
    aria-required="true" name="j_idt87:extended" id="j_idt87:extended" 
    role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false"/>
```

And do something with css like

```
input[aria-required="true"], input[data-p-required="true"] {
    background-color: lightblue !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

(if you make the selectors more specific, the !important can be left out)

And this with some jquery might work to, according to google (not tested)

```
$("input[aria-required]").after("*");
```

or

```
$("input[aria-required]").before("*");
```

But this has to be re-applied after each ajax call that updates the inputs. So I'd go with the first or second